# Comparing against a dynamic value in a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON array:

```
[ { "Alpha": {"min": "1", "max": "2"} }, { "Beta": {"min": "10", "max": "20"} }]
```

The plan is to have the user select Alpha or Beta, and then they can select how many units they need.

```
var selectedUnit = $("#entry_field").val();
$.getJSON("/json-url/", function(data) {
    var a = data[0].Alpha.min;          // This works
    var b = data[0].selectedUnit.min    // This does not work, and I'm not sure why
    var c = data[0].Beta.min;           // This does not work, but I understand why
    var d = data.Alpha.min;             // This does not work, and I'm not sure why
    var e = data.selectedUnit.min;      // This does not work, and is going to be what I need
    if (e > selectedValue) {
        alert("You are below the minimum units");
    }
});
```

I'm aware there's multiple things preventing me from setting var e correctly, but I'm not sure the best way to go about setting this value.

Comment: Do you control the structure of data returned in the ajax request? If so using an object literal instead of array would simplify this  `{ "Alpha": {"min": "1", "max": "2"}, "Beta": {"min": "10", "max": "20"}}`

Comment: I do, but I was having a hard time with my fetchxml formatting it correctly. Because of your comment I decided to give it another try and now it's formatted as you've suggested.

Comment: So assuming  `$("#entry_field")` has values like "Alpha" and "Beta" then you can do `var wantedObject = data[selectedUnit]; console.log(wantedObject.min)`. You have to use `[]` notation for variable property names